# Count total number of contacts from address book - iOS

Tags: ios, contacts

How can I count the total number of contacts from the address book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
// ...

- (int)contactsCount {    
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );
    CFRelease( addressBook );
    return (int)nPeople;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Erica Sadun's [ABContactHelper](https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper).

At least as a starting point.

In ABContactsHelper.h there are declarations:

```
+ (int) contactsCount;
+ (int) contactsWithImageCount;
+ (int) contactsWithoutImageCount;
+ (int) numberOfGroups;
```

I think it's a little outdated so you might have to tweak the code a little.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *people = [book people];
int count = [[book people] count];
```

Comment: That's an OSX class that doesn't exist on iOS.

Comment: NSArray *people = [book people]; int count = [[book people] count];